# jsfiddle - phising warning in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsfiddle, blowfish

I'm getting this message after I press "run":

> Reported Phishing Website Ahead! Google Chrome has blocked access to
>   fiddle.jshell.net. This website has been reported as a phishing
>   website. Phishing websites are designed to trick you into disclosing
>   your login, password or other sensitive information by disguising
>   themselves as other websites you may trust. Learn more Go back
>   Advanced

Here's a screenshot :
[image: "Reported Phishing Website Ahead" Google Chrome screenshot]

Comment: I'm getting the same warning on Chromium Version 25. We have the option to report incorrect phiishing : http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?tpl=googlechrome&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2F&hl=en-US

Comment: Getting the same warning... it wasn't there like a couple hours ago

Comment: Happens in Firefox as well. They both use Google's phishing service. My guess is they labelled JSFiddle as a false positive after receiving a certain threshold of reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some informations about fiddle.jshell.net:

http://www.webutations.org/go/review/fiddle.jshell.net and http://support.clean-mx.com/clean-mx/phishing.php?domain=jshell.net&sort=id%20DESC

Also, here Google explains Google Chrome 17+ Speed and Security policies: http://chrome.blogspot.ro/2012/01/speed-and-security.html

However, people can submit pishing websites that will be analized and tested.

Google's Diagnostic Webpage: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=fiddle.jshell.net

My suggestion is to upgrade your browser version even though Google says that it is *Secured.*

Comment: Looks like the fiddle (don't click) : http://fiddle.jshell.net/Tradezshowroom/SBdxm/1/show/light/ is making the warning message.

Comment: Fortunately I get no warning.